# How to get a preview of a second monitor?

Tags: x11, manjaro

I have connected a projector, but I don't see the image of this second "monitor" very well (it's quite far). **Is it possible to get a live preview of this second monitor in a small window on a first monitor?** Something like "picture in picture".

Comment: Have you come across `xwd` ? you affectively want to take a screenshot of the other window and display it, but it's not real-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run 2 programs, in 2 terminals; an `x11vnc` server and an `xvncviewer`. E.g.

```
$ x11vnc -viewonly -clip 1920x1080+1920+0 -scale 0.4
```

and

```
$ xvncviewer :0
```

The `x11vnc` server sets up a VNC view connection to the indicated screen region of the main display. I've assumed a xinerama set up with the local monitor 1920x1080 to the left and the remote projector 1920x1080 to the right; i.e., the projector is at +1920+0 with display size 1920x1080.

You would change those to suit your actual set up. E.g. 1024x768+1920+0 if the projector has resolution 1024x768 and is (notionally) to the right of the first monitor with resolution 1920x1080.

You may use `xrandr` to see your actual set up.

I've suggested using `xvncviewer` as VNC viewer. There are a number of other viewers to choose from.